# Understanding David Deutsch's assertion about the laws of physics as emerging from those of biology

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

In the Chapter 1 of the Fabric of Reality, David Deutsch says the following:

> There is no reason to regard high-level theories as in any way 'second-class citizens'.
>
> Each of them has implications for the others, but not all the implications can be stated, for they are emergent properties of the other theories' domains.
>
> In fact, the very terms 'high level' and 'low level' are misnomers. The laws of biology, say, are high-level, emergent consequences of the laws of physics. **But logically, some of the laws of physics are then 'emergent' consequences of the laws of biology**.

It is the last bit that I grapple with. How is it that the highighted assertion follows "logically" from the premise?

In my mind, if we say that the LoB (laws of biology) are high-level and are derived from the LoP (laws of physics), it does not follow that some of LoP are derived from LoB.

Comment: You need to give more details, but I assume he is referring to the idea that some of the laws would be of the "if and only if" form. If "P if and only if Q", then Q is a consequence of P, but P is also a consequence of Q.

Comment: Deutsch's point is that logic does not care about our preferred direction of deriving, just as it does not care which of two correlated things is "causing" which. If something in physics can be used to logically derive something about biology then *that* can be turned around to derive something about physics. However, many view reduction (from less fundamental to more fundamental) as something stronger than mere logical dependence, and asymmetric, and so see  Deutsch's too clever by half maneuver as invalid.

Comment: Even if one views reduction purely as a matter of logical deduction, it may be that information is lost in going from a lower level fundamental physics description to a description at a higher level, so the precise lower level description can't be derived from the higher level one, see for example the distinction between microstates and macrostates in [classical statistical mechanics](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Epeastman/statmech/statisticaldescription.html)

Comment: Maybe the anthropic principle(s), & the observation time may be deeply linked to what we need to have experiences rather than 'out there'